# Microsoft Teams: How to add notifications to the activity feed?

Tags: office365, botframework, microsoft-teams

How can I push notifications to a users activity feed in Teams?

[This documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/activityfeed) suggests its possible by setting a `channelData` property. Some things about this:

1. When using `setChannelData` in the [Microsoft Teams Getting Started Sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-get-started) it tells me it's deprecated and I should use `sourceEvent()` instead:
   [image]
2. For several weeks now there is a note in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/activityfeed) saying *"The following features are coming soon to the Public Developer Preview."* - which is not helpful and differs from other parts of the documentation. Is it in preview or not?
   [image]
3. It does not seem to work at all.

So we have a deprecated, soon to come function that does not work. How is the current state of this? Which documentation is correct, which outdated? If `sourceEvent`was to set - how is the syntax?

Any help on this topic is appreciated.

**Addition:**

In the app manifest there is a property `isNotificationOnly`. I set it, it did change nothing. Do I need this?

Comment: Are you running the [Developer Preview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/publicpreview) build?

Comment: @Marc Yes, Tenant runs in first release mode, Teams app runs in Developer Preview mode. (Tested yesterday with sideloaded app, chatting with a bot 1:1 as well as in a channel.) Goal: let the bot proactively "communicate" with a user by pushing a notification to the activity stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug with activity feed notifications. This will be shipped in Q1 2018.